# Mongo - quick exports of all documents without performace hit on other queries?

Tags: performance, mongodb, export

I need Mongo cluster doing 2 operations:

1. **get/update a single document** - Mongo is great for realtime changes, excelent speed.
2. **export all documents into JSON file** (one file for a category, there are cca 15 categories) - **this is very slow**, when I use regular query. May be I do not know, what command or options to use ... or I would need to fit it whole into RAM, which is expesive. Even replication to a new mongo instance is much faster (takes hours) then a query and writing data to disk (takes days).

I have about 10m documents. Mongo data on disk has 250Gb. There are cca 15 categories for which I need separate files (at the moment all documents are in 1 collection regardless of category).

Which command should I use to export all data into files in a couple of hours?
How large aws instances should I use to speed it up, but not to pay too much for RAM. Would it help? Operation 2) must not cause a performace hit for operation 1) -- I cannot stop Mongo and use mongoexport.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of servers you are using but this may provide some further insights regarding the export/file creation performance and not shutting off mongo. One presumes you are working with a sharded and replicated cluster.

In my case I am on Azure VMs running Windows server in a replicated and sharded cluster. So I would take a copy of the Azure blobs associated with the data disks on a secondary in each RS. You should stop your balancer and lock the db on the secondary to do this. This should take a couple of minutes at most to copy only 250gb. Then I would restore the blobs to disks on a new VM.

Then you could query data out of this VM without affecting your cluster's performance. You may additionally add indexing fir this export process since you are on a separate instance now.

Personally I use PowerShell to do this in Azure. Golang may be a better choice to write your queries in due to its parallel capabilities if JavaScript via the mongo shell fails you. I've had JS work faster than python code but it also depends on what you know.

This is just one way but it does address some of the criteria you posted.